# How to clear data in specific state index using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to create a function to clear the table row data on specific state index. This quite new for me. I know how to do this in jquery, however I work on javascript library. no error but the data is not clearing if I start clicking the button.

**Goal set the value empty**

[image: Goal]

**Current Output**

[image: Current Output]

**Here is my Jsx code**

```
<span className="fa  fa-minus" onClick={this.ClearRowData} index={i}></span>
```

**ClearRowData Function**

```
ClearRowData = async (index) => {
   
    const value = {
        customer: "",
        bank: "",
        branch: "",
        checkNo: "",
        checkDate: "",
        amount: "",
        remarks: "",
        
    }

    const rows = [...this.state.rows]
    var index = rows.indexOf(index)

    if(index !== -1) {
        this.setState({
            ...this.state.rows,
            value
        })
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you want to archive. Did you want to remove row from list or clear attributes of selected row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `ClearRowData` function shouldn't be an `async` function because you are not doing anything asynchronous inside it.

Assuming that `this.state.rows` is an array of objects similar to `value` defined in `ClearRowData` function, you can use `map()` method to update the state.

Inside the callback function of `map()` method, check if the `index` parameter's value is equal to the index passed to the callback function of the `map()` method as an argument; if they both are equal, then return the `value` object, otherwise return the current object as it is.

```
clearRowData = (index) => {
  
    const value = { ... };

    const updatedRows = this.state.rows.map((obj, i) => {
       return index == i ? value : obj;
    });
    
    this.setState({ rows: updatedRows });   
}
```

You also need to call `clearRowData` function correctly. Change

```
onClick={this.ClearRowData}
```

to

```
onClick={() => this.ClearRowData(i)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array.filter method to remove an item immutably. So something like...

```
rows.filter((row, index) => index !== indexToRemove
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're expecting your `i` value to be passed to the function as a parameter, but it is not.  It's being supplied as a property to the `span` element, which doesn't need it and ignores it.  Instead the click event is being passed as a parameter.

If you don't want the event and just want your `i` value, pass it explicitly:

```
<span className="fa  fa-minus" onClick={() => this.ClearRowData(i)}></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example can help you.

```js
const clear = ( index ) => {
    setRows( rows.filter( row => row.id !== index ) )
}
```